# Strange Cannot read property 'threads' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi I have programmed this on NodeJS:

```
Thread.findById(req.body.thread_id, function(err, thread){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    // If user is the sender delete from his list of threads
    if(thread.sender._id.equals(req.user._id))
    {
        console.log(thread.sender.threads);
        for (var i=0; i<thread.sender.threads.length; i++)
        {
```

And I getting an error on the line of the for statement:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'threads' of undefined

The strange thing is that thread.user is not undefined and if I watch the console it is printing the threads for the order "console.log(thread.sender.threads);"

I have spent more than 4 hours with this error so any help will be really appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What does `console.log(thread)` print, because its saying that `thread` does not have a property `sender` - that should be your first clue to debug this

Comment: Hi Alex! It prints the thread object with the sender property correctly filled. That's why I found this so strange because the thread.sender seems to be ok.